# View not presenting properly on iPhone plus models

Tags: ios, swift, presentmodalviewcontroller

In iPhone 7 simulator, I have a view called `cartView` which looks like so...

[image]

On pressing the next button on the `cartView` at the bottom, another view is presented like so...

[image]

This presented view is called `presentedView`.

The code written on the press of the next button on the `cartView` is this...

```
let vc = PresentedUserDetailsViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In the `presentedView`, these have been declared before the `viewDidLoad`...

```
lazy var backdropView: UIView = {
    let bdView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    bdView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    return bdView
}()
```

`let menuHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2`

```
var isPresenting = false

init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    modalPresentationStyle = .custom
    transitioningDelegate = self
}
```

Finally, at the end, an extension is also given like so...

```
extension PresentedUserDetailsViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 1
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)
        guard let toVC = toViewController else { return }
        isPresenting = !isPresenting

        if isPresenting == true {
            containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)

            menuView.frame.origin.y += menuHeight
            backdropView.alpha = 0

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
                self.menuView.frame.origin.y -= self.menuHeight
                self.backdropView.alpha = 1
            }, completion: { (finished) in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
                self.menuView.frame.origin.y += self.menuHeight
                self.backdropView.alpha = 0
            }, completion: { (finished) in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the app in a plus type iPhone model (say iPhone 6 plus or iPhone 7 plus) and press the next button on the `cartView` this is what I'm getting...

[image]

Here, I've just colored the `presentedView` to make it distinct. In this case, the `presentedView` not only does not fill the entire screen size but part of the `cartView` is also seen behind including the next button of the `cartView`.

How can I make the `presentedView` to appear properly on a plus type iPhone model like they appear in the iPhone 7 model (the 2nd screenshot from top)

**EDIT 1: THE SCREENSHOT ON iPhone 6 plus AFTER MAKING CHANGES..**

[image]

**EDIT: 2 As seen in iPad Air 2...**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set constraints when you add subview, in this case.

```
containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)
```

use autolayout, to set constraints

**UPDATED: **

```
extension UIView{
     public func attachTo(view : UIView, animated : Bool = true){

            if(animated){
                self.alpha = 0
            }
            else{
                self.alpha = 1
            }

            view.addSubview(self)
            // self.frame = view.bounds

            self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.topAnchor).isActive = true
            self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            self.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            self.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.superview!.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true


            if(animated){
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    self.alpha = 1
                })
            }
        }
}
```

now, remove

> containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)

and add this :

> toVC.view.attachTo(view: containerView)

Comment: if you don't mind, could u maybe show how exactly @maku..?

Comment: It worked almost fine @maku..but now, towards the right an empty strip is shown as I have shown in the screenshot (edited the question) at the end..

Comment: well, the view that is presented, can you show how have you created?

Comment: check constraints also for the dimm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171382/discussion-between-bws-and-maku).

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you get wrong frame in `let bdView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)`. try to use autolayout

Comment: bit confused @薛永伟 you have any suggestions..?

Comment: override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        bdView = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    }

Answer (score 0):

After `containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)` add following:

`toVC.view.autoresizingMasks = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]`